# How to convert string to variable and set attributes of them in jquery

Tags: jquery, string, attributes

In C# When we want find a variable or object we use (Object)this.FindName(string)

But i don't know, what is jquery script for find a object or a global variable such as this code

```
var bln1 = bln2 = bln3 = bln4 = false;
var name;
for ($nums = 1; $nums <= 4; $nums++)
{          
   var name = 'bln' + $nums;
   // eval(name) = false; // this code give errors
}
```

How to fix this problem?Thanks

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C#. That is client side Javascript code. Also, you need to explain a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use array instead of using variable

```
var bln = [false, false, false]
```

If array is not the choice then use window[variablename]

```
var name = 'bln' + $nums;
window[name] = false;
```

Comment: ok, but i have problem with find boolean from string, i need convert string to variable

Comment: how can use windows[name] or window[bln] for set it to false or true?

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I found it